# What is this anti-pattern? Invoking a function for a latent effect

Tags: anti-patterns

Is there a name for this anti-pattern? The best way I can describe it is "invoking a function for a latent effect, not for its primary purpose".

1. Function A does X and Z
2. Function B does Y and Z
3. Function A calls Function B in order to do Z.

Problems with this anti-pattern:

1. Lack of code expressiveness
2. Redundant code execution

Cause: Unwillingness to refactor existing code and create a new function

Example:

```java
void afterWifeSaysHello() {
  // I need to say "hello!" back to my wife!
  // I do the same thing when the doorbell rings so...
  afterDoorbellRings();
}

void afterDoorbellRings() {
  openDoor();
  // pretend that saying hello is more complex than one simple line of code.
  say("hello!");
  closeDoor();
}
```

It should be written as:

```java
void afterWifeSaysHello() {
  sayHello();
}

void afterDoorbellRings() {
  openDoor();
  sayHello();
  closeDoor();
}

void sayHello() {
  say("hello!");
}
```

Developer A: "You shouldn't call `afterDoorbellRings` in `afterWifeSaysHello` because the doorbell didn't ring."
Developer B: "It's just the function name. `afterDoorbellRings` does what I need."
Developer A: "But you're opening the door for no reason."
Developer B: "The door is still closed in the end so it doesn't matter."

Comment: Well,  it goes against the [single responsibility principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)

Answer (score 0):

There is a coupling problem in the original `afterDoorbellRings` method in that it assumes that the "say hello" functionality is only needed in the context of the door opening and closing. The anti-pattern you describe could also happen where the other parts of `afterDoorbellRings` don't change state, rather than cancel each other out as in your open/close door example. I'm sure this anti-pattern is common enough, but I've never seen it given a name other than "bad coding"!